# Python insertion sorting a csv by row

Tags: python, csv, sorting, multidimensional-array, insertion-sort

My objective is to use an insertion sort to sort the contents of a csv file by the numbers in the first column for example I want this:

```
[[7831703,  Christian,  Schmidt]
[2299817,   Amber,  Cohen]
[1964394,   Gregory,    Hanson]
[1984288,   Aaron,  White]
[9713285,   Alexander,  Kirk]
[7025528,   Janice, Lee]
[6441979,   Sarah,  Browning]
[8815776,   Rick,   Wallace]
[2395480,   Martin, Weinstein]
[1927432,   Stephen,    Morrison]]
```

and sort it to:

```
[[1927432,  Stephen,    Morrison]
[1964394,   Gregory,    Hanson]
[1984288,   Aaron,  White]
[2299817,   Amber,  Cohen]
[2395480,   Martin, Weinstein]
[6441979,   Sarah,  Browning]
[7025528,   Janice, Lee]
[7831703,   Christian,  Schmidt]
[8815776,   Rick,   Wallace]
[9713285,   Alexander,  Kirk]]
```

based off the numbers in the first column within python my current code looks like:

```
import csv
with open('EmployeeList.csv', newline='') as File:  
    reader = csv.reader(File)
    readList = list(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

def insertionSort(readList): 
  #Traverse through 1 to the len of the list
    for row in range(len(readList)):
# Traverse through 1 to len(arr) 
        for i in range(1, len(readList[row])): 
    
            key = readList[row][i] 
    


    # Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are 
    # greater than key, to one position ahead 
    # of their current position
            j = i-1
            while j >=0 and key < readList[row][j] : 
                    readList[row] = readList[row] 
                    j -= 1
            readList[row] = key 

insertionSort(readList)
print ("Sorted array is:") 
for i in range(len(readList)): 
    print ( readList[i])
```

The code can already sort the contents of a 2d array, but as it is it tries to sort everything.
I think if I got rid of the [] it would work but in testing it hasn't given what I needed.
To try to clarify again I want to sort the rows positions based off of the first columns numerical value.

Comment: By the way, the last part of the code you could do `for x in readList: print (x)`. You don't need index like some other languaes. Just loop throuhg items of iterable object. That is more pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand your need right. But you have a list and you need to sort it?  Why you don't you just use `sort` method in list object?

```
>>> data = [[7831703,  "Christian",  "Schmidt"],
... [2299817,   "Amber",  "Cohen"],
... [1964394,   "Gregory",    "Hanson"],
... [1984288,   "Aaron",  "White"],
... [9713285,   "Alexander",  "Kirk"],
... [7025528,   "Janice", "Lee"],
... [6441979,   "Sarah",  "Browning"],
... [8815776,   "Rick",   "Wallace"],
... [2395480,   "Martin", "Weinstein"],
... [1927432,   "Stephen",    "Morrison"]]
>>> data.sort()
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
[[1927432, 'Stephen', 'Morrison'],
 [1964394, 'Gregory', 'Hanson'],
 [1984288, 'Aaron', 'White'],
 [2299817, 'Amber', 'Cohen'],
 [2395480, 'Martin', 'Weinstein'],
 [6441979, 'Sarah', 'Browning'],
 [7025528, 'Janice', 'Lee'],
 [7831703, 'Christian', 'Schmidt'],
 [8815776, 'Rick', 'Wallace'],
 [9713285, 'Alexander', 'Kirk']]
>>>
```

Note that here we have first element parsed as integer. It is important if you want to sort it by numerical value (99 comes before 100).

And don't be confused by importing `pprint`. You don't need it to sort. I just used is to get nicer output in console.

And also note that List.sort() is in-place method. It doesn't return sorted list but sorts the list itself.

*** EDIT ***

Here is two different apporach to sort function. Both could be heavily optimized but I hope you get some ideas how this can be done. Both should work and you can add some print commands in loops to see what happens there.

First recursive version. It orders the list a little bit on every run until it is ordered.

```py
def recursiveSort(readList):
    # You don't want to mess original data, so we handle copy of it
    data = readList.copy()
    changed = False
    res = []
    while len(data): #while 1 shoudl work here as well because eventually we break the loop
        if len(data) == 1: 
            # There is only one element left. Let's add it to end of our result.
            res.append(data[0])
            break;
        if data[0][0] > data[1][0]:
            # We compare first two elements in list. 
            # If first one is bigger, we remove second element from original list and add it next to the result set. 
            # Then we raise changed flag to tell that we changed the order of original list.
            res.append(data.pop(1))
            changed = True
        else:
            # otherwise we remove first element from the list and add next to the result list.
            res.append(data.pop(0))
    
    if not changed:
       #if no changes has been made,  the list is in order
       return res
    else:
       #if we made changes, we sort list one more time.
       return recursiveSort(res)
```

And here is a iterative version, closer your original function.

```
def iterativeSort(readList):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(readList)):
       print (res)
       #loop through the original list
       if len(res) == 0:
          # if we don't have any items in our result list, we add first element here.
          res.append(readList[i])
       else:
          done = False
          for j in range(len(res)):
              #loop through the result list this far
              if res[j][0] > readList[i][0]:
                  #if our item in list is smaller than element in res list, we insert it here
                  res.insert(j, readList[i])
                  done = True
                  break
          if not done:
             #if our item in list is bigger than all the items in result list, we put it last.
             res.append(readList[i])
       print(res)
    return res
```

Comment: I need to use my insertion sort function to do it

Comment: Your insertionSort function doesn't return anything. Is that for purpose.

Comment: You can even use `lambda readList: readList.sort()` to do the same if you don't need to return anything from your function, just call it and sort your list in-place.

Comment: Or is this a homework and you need to implement a sort function? If so, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I'm technically not a student I'm not involved in any program or course. I'm entirely self taught. For this I need to use my insertionSort function that I made and cannot use any prebuilt sort function. This is so that I can learn about array manipulation, which from what I understand is a valuable skill to have.

Comment: Ok. But to make sure. You want to sort list by integer on  idx=0 of inner lists? And your function doesn't need to care about other elements in inner list.

Comment: Yes I want it to sort the row information based off of the info in index=0

Comment: Would you happen to know a way to modify my currently existing insertionSort function or possibly a selections sort?

Comment: To be honest I don't quite understand what is your idea in your method. Could you edit your question and add comment your code. What you want to achieve in each row. Like I've commented my code.